# Keras Stateful LSTM - strange val loss

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to do a one-step ahead contrived stock market prediction and I'm unsure if I am doing everything correctly as my validation loss does not go down and my graphs look off to me.

With no dropout I get the following - it looks like a common case of overfitting?: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4hMP.png)

However I would expect the predictions to basically mirror the training data in this case as it has learnt it's pattern but instead I get this graph when plotting y_train vs the predictions:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvfU9.png)

Strangely when plotting y_test vs predictions it looks more accurate:
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPLDZ.png)

How could y_train be so far off with such a low training MSE and y_test be more accurate with a high MSE?

When adding dropout, the model simply fails to learn or just learns much slower on the training set like this (only 10 epochs to cut down on training time but the pattern holds of val loss not decreasing). 
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY2tY.png)

Some information about the model.
My data shapes are as follows:

```python
x_train size is: (172544, 20, 197)
x_test size is: (83968, 20, 197)
y_train size is: (172544, 1)
y_test size is: (83968, 1)
```

X is set up as 197 features at timesteps [0,1,2,..19] and has a corresponding Y label at timestep [20]. The repeats for the next sequence [1,2,3...20] and Y label [21] and so on.

All data is normalized to mean 0, std_dev 1 (on the training set) then applied to the test set.

Code for the model:

```python
batch_size = 512
DROPOUT = 0.0
timesteps = x_train.shape[1]
data_dim = x_train.shape[2]

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, stateful=True, return_sequences=True, implementation=2, 
               dropout=DROPOUT,
               batch_input_shape=(batch_size, timesteps, data_dim)))
model.add(LSTM(256, stateful=True, return_sequences=True, implementation=2, 
               dropout=DROPOUT))
model.add(LSTM(256, stateful=True, return_sequences=False, implementation=2, 
               dropout=DROPOUT))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear')) 

nadam = Nadam()
model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer=nadam,
              metrics=['mse','mae','mape'])

history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
          epochs=100,batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, verbose=1, callbacks=[reduce_lr])
```

EDIT: Even when using two samples the same happens

```python
x_train size is: (2, 2, 197)
x_test size is: (2, 2, 197)
y_train size is: (2, 1)
y_test size is: (2, 1)
```

[y_train vs predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lFLR3.png)